# php multidimensional array - how to find min value and return key

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a unique problem that I cannot seem to find an answer to.

I ultimately want to find the index of the array that has the min value on 'price'.

```
$r = array (
array('id' => 1526,'name'=>"Expedited Parcel",'day'=>1,'price'=>10),
array('id' => 1234,'name'=>"XpressPost Parcel",'day'=>2,'price'=>20),
array('id' => 5345,'name'=>"Internation Shipping",'day'=>7,'price'=>100),
array('id' => 1332,'name'=>"Snail Mail Shipping",'day'=>15,'price'=>10));
```

You might also notice that the 'price' has duplicate values of 10. In this case, would it be possible to then compare the `$r[0]['day']` and `$r[3]['day']` values and then come up with `$index=0`? And if PRICE and DAY are the same, then either one is fine.

The result I'd like would be `print "Free Shipping".$r[$index]['name']." ".$r[$index]['day']." Business Days".`

**EDIT**
I found out my array is different, there is no index but now a name reference.

`$r = array (
'DOM.EP' => array('id' => 1526,'name'=>"Expedited Parcel",'day'=>1,'price'=>10),
'DOM.PC' => array('id' => 1234,'name'=>"XpressPost Parcel",'day'=>2,'price'=>20),
'DOM.IS' => array('id' => 5345,'name'=>"Internation Shipping",'day'=>7,'price'=>100),
'DOM.SM' => array('id' => 1332,'name'=>"Snail Mail Shipping",'day'=>15,'price'=>10)
);`

**LAST EDIT** Thank you everyone for your help! I've gone ahead and combined code @Kolob Canyon and also @sathish R to get my final code.

```
$min = 9999999999;
$minDay = 9999999999;
$idx = null;
foreach ($r as $key => $value) {
    if($min > $r[$key]['price']) {
            $min = $r[$key]['price'];
            $minDay = $r[$key]['day'];
            $idx = $key;
        } 
        else if ($min == $r[$key]['price']) {
            if ($minDay > $r[$key]['day']){
                $minDay = $r[$key]['day'];
                $idx = $key;
            }
        }
}

if($idx != null) {
        echo "Free Shipping ". $r[$idx]['name'] . " " . $r[$idx]['day'] . " Business Days";
    }
```

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4497810/min-and-max-in-multidimensional-array

Comment: Let me know this is what you want:- https://eval.in/821197

Comment: JJ_StackO  did you checked the comments as well as answers?

Comment: Thanks everyone... ! It's been a while since I've programmed and all these are very helpful! I appreciate the communities responses. I'm going to go through them and see if I understand it all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feels like I'm solving your homework question:

```
$min = PHP_INT_MAX;
$idx = null;
for($i=0; $i < count($r); $i++)
{
       if($min > $r[$i]['price']) 
       { 
            $min = $r[$i]['price'];
            $idx = $i;
       }
}

if($idx != null) {
    echo "Free Shipping". $r[$idx]['name'] . " " . $r[$idx]['day'] . " Business Days"; 
}
```

**Answer to your edit.**

```
<?php
$r = array (
        'DOM.EP' => array('id' => 1526,'name'=>"Expedited Parcel",'day'=>1,'price'=>10),
        'DOM.PC' => array('id' => 1234,'name'=>"XpressPost Parcel",'day'=>2,'price'=>20),
        'DOM.IS' => array('id' => 5345,'name'=>"Internation Shipping",'day'=>7,'price'=>100),
        'DOM.SM' => array('id' => 1332,'name'=>"Snail Mail Shipping",'day'=>15,'price'=>10)
);

$min = PHP_INT_MAX;
$idx = null;
foreach ($r as $key => $value) {
        if($min > $r[$key]['price'])
        {
            $min = $r[$key]['price'];
            $idx = $key;
        }
    }

    if($idx != null) {
        echo "Free Shipping ". $r[$idx]['name'] . " " . $r[$idx]['day'] . " Business Days";
    }
?>
```

Comment: I havent programmed in a long time and I remember why I have this love/hate relationship with it :) I get enjoyment when I figure something out but get extremely frustrated when it doesn't return the results I want lol.

Answer (score 1):

You could use simple for loop to achieve your result.

`$r = array (
array('id' => 1526,'name'=>"Expedited Parcel",'day'=>1,'price'=>10),
array('id' => 1234,'name'=>"XpressPost Parcel",'day'=>2,'price'=>20),
array('id' => 5345,'name'=>"Internation Shipping",'day'=>7,'price'=>100),
array('id' => 1332,'name'=>"Snail Mail Shipping",'day'=>15,'price'=>10));

$minPrice=PHP_INT_MAX ,$minDay =PHP_INT_MAX,$index=-1 ;
$i=0;

foreach($r as $d)
{
   if($d['price'] < $minPrice)
   {
       $minPrice = $d['price'];
       $minDay = $d['day'];
       $index = $i;
   }
   else if($d['price'] == $minPrice )
   {
       if($d['day'] < $minDay )
       {
           $minDay = $d['day'];
             $index = $i;
       }
   }
   $i++;
}

if($index >=0 ) {
    echo "Free Shipping". $r[$index]['name'] . " " . $r[$index]['day'] . " 
    Business Days"; 
}`

Comment: I tried using this and it worked great! However, the my array was changed into a multidimensional without the index.

`$r = array (
'DOM.EP' => array('id' => 1526,'name'=>"Expedited Parcel",'day'=>1,'price'=>10),
'DOM.PC' => array('id' => 1234,'name'=>"XpressPost Parcel",'day'=>2,'price'=>20),
'DOM.IS' => array('id' => 5345,'name'=>"Internation Shipping",'day'=>7,'price'=>100),
'DOM.SM' => array('id' => 1332,'name'=>"Snail Mail Shipping",'day'=>15,'price'=>10)
);`

Comment: I can reference the $r['DOM.EP']['name'] directly but confused how would $index pull 'DOM.EP' now? Would I use array_keys in replace of $index = $i?

Answer (score 0):

you can do as following :

```
$dealersMin = min(array_column($dealers, 'count'));

$dealersWithMinCount = array_filter($dealers, function ($dealer) {
    global $dealersMin;
    return ($dealer['count'] == $dealersMin);
});
```

var_dump($dealersWithMinCount[array_rand($dealersWithMinCount)]['id']);

Hope this will work....

You can see more here https://eval.in/819623

Comment: using `global` is a bad practice. You can replace it with `function ($dealer) use ($dealersMin)`

Comment: Hi there! I did look at this one previously, it returned the value and not the specific key unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

### Using native function asort to reorder your array

```
<?php

// your array
$r = array (
        array('id' => 1526,'name'=>"Expedited Parcel",'day'=>1,'price'=>10),
        array('id' => 1234,'name'=>"XpressPost Parcel",'day'=>2,'price'=>20),
        array('id' => 5345,'name'=>"Internation Shipping",'day'=>7,'price'=>100),
        array('id' => 1332,'name'=>"Snail Mail Shipping",'day'=>15,'price'=>10)
);

// getting the columns
$col_id     = array_column($r, 'id');   
$col_name   = array_column($r, 'name');
$col_day    = array_column($r, 'day');
$col_price  = array_column($r, 'price');


// reordering the columns - first the price, second the day
$new_r = array();

$i=0;
foreach($col_id as $id)
{
    $new_r[] = array(
                    'price'=>$col_price[$i],
                    'day'=>$col_day[$i],
                    'id'=>$id,
                    'name'=>$col_name[$i],
                    );
    $i++;
}

// asort the new array - php will do what you want following the order of the columns       
asort($new_r);      
var_dump($new_r);   

//Then get the desired element (the first in the array above)

$free = array_shift($new_r); //get first element of the array $new_r
print "Free Shipping: ".$free['name']." ".$free['day']." Business Days";
```

## Output of the script:

```
array (size=4)
  0 => 
    array (size=4)
      'price' => int 10
      'day' => int 1
      'id' => int 1526
      'name' => string 'Expedited Parcel' (length=16)
  3 => 
    array (size=4)
      'price' => int 10
      'day' => int 15
      'id' => int 1332
      'name' => string 'Snail Mail Shipping' (length=19)
  1 => 
    array (size=4)
      'price' => int 20
      'day' => int 2
      'id' => int 1234
      'name' => string 'XpressPost Parcel' (length=17)
  2 => 
    array (size=4)
      'price' => int 100
      'day' => int 7
      'id' => int 5345
      'name' => string 'Internation Shipping' (length=20)

Free Shipping: Expedited Parcel 1 Business Days
```

Make tests changing the values of the prices and days.

Answer (score 0):

Code :

```
<?php
$temp_array = array();
$r = array (
array('id' => 1526,'name'=>"Expedited Parcel",'day'=>1,'price'=>10),
array('id' => 1234,'name'=>"XpressPost Parcel",'day'=>2,'price'=>20),
array('id' => 5345,'name'=>"Internation Shipping",'day'=>7,'price'=>100),
array('id' => 1332,'name'=>"Snail Mail Shipping",'day'=>15,'price'=>10));

foreach($r as $row)
{
    if(count($temp_array)!=0)
    {
        if($temp_array['price']>$row['price'])
        {
            $temp_array['id'] = $row['id'];
            $temp_array['name'] = $row['name'];
            $temp_array['day'] = $row['day'];
            $temp_array['price'] = $row['price'];
        }
        else if($temp_array['price'] == $row['price'])
        {
            if($temp_array['day']>$row['day'])
            {
                $temp_array['id'] = $row['id'];
                $temp_array['name'] = $row['name'];
                $temp_array['day'] = $row['day'];
                $temp_array['price'] = $row['price'];
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $temp_array['id'] = $row['id'];
        $temp_array['name'] = $row['name'];
        $temp_array['day'] = $row['day'];
        $temp_array['price'] = $row['price'];
    }
}
echo "Free Shipping :".$temp_array['name'].", ".$temp_array['day']." Business Days";
?>
```

Output :

```
Free Shipping :Expedited Parcel, 1 Business Days
```